# How to use the Toast Ui Image Editor React library with includeUi set to false?

Tags: toast-ui-image-editor

**Summary**

I am encountering an issue while using Toast Ui Image Editor React library.
I can't figure out how to import an image and set up an editing area while passing the `includeUi` parameter as `false`.

I have tried several approaches, including the `loadImageFromUrl` and `addImageObject` methods, but without success.

How can I use the library without the UI to integrate it directly into my React component?

**Code**

```
const ImageEditingContent = () => {
  const editorRef = createRef();
  const imagePath = '...';

  return (
    <div className="hk-pt-1">
      <div className="hk-w-140 hk-h-[315px]">
        <ImageEditor
          ref={editorRef}
          includeUi={false}
          cssMaxHeight={315}
          cssMaxWidth={560}
          usageStatistics={false}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="hk-mt-5 hk-m-auto hk-w-fit">
        <></>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Version**

^3.15.2